# Android Volley ImageListener onResponse behaviour

Tags: android, caching, request, response, android-volley

I'm using Android Volley Library and my question should be easy to answer, if you know it ;).

I need to know how `com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageListener` exactly behaves when 
handling successful responses. The docs says

```
The call flow is this: 1. Upon being attached to a request, 
onResponse(response, true) will be invoked to reflect any cached data 
that was already available. If the data was available, response.getBitmap() will 
be non-null. 2. After a network response returns, only one of the following 
cases will happen: - onResponse(response, false) will be called if the 
image was loaded. or - onErrorResponse will be called if there was an error 
loading the image.
```

What I want to know is this: does that mean that I can have `onResponse` called twice (first with `isImmediate` set to `false` and then set to `true`)? Can I rely on that? I mean will it always be like this (if the image loading is succesful)?

I'm trying to do something like this

```
imageLoader.get(image.getUrl(), new ImageListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        callback.call(null, error);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(ImageContainer response,
                            boolean isImmediate) {
                        if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                            callback.call(response.getBitmap(), null);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I need `callback.call()` to be called when the image could be loaded succesfully and I also need `response.getBitmap()` to return the actual bitmap and not `null`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to know is this: does that mean that I can have onResponse called twice (first with isImmediate set to false and then set to true)? Can I rely on that? I mean will it always be like this (if the image loading is succesful)?

Short answer: **yes**.

Unless the implementation of this class is changed (and I highly doubt that will happen), you can rely on this call order being respected.

If it helps, I gave some detail on the three possible response cases in another answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32464875/3227795