# Volley, How many times the onResponse in ImageLoader.ImageListener called

Tags: android, android-intent, android-volley

I‘ using `Volley` to do internet requests. I think the `onResponse` method should be called only once when receive a response, but I found it called twice.

here is my code:

```
YVolley.getInstance(context).getImageLoader().get(category.child.get(i).icon, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                    Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), response.getBitmap());
                    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, GeneralUtil.dip2px(context, 45), GeneralUtil.dip2px(context, 45));
                    button.setCompoundDrawables(null, drawable, null, null);
                    Log.i("swifter", "get icon ... success == "+url);
                }

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.i("swifter", "get drawable icon error...");
                }
            });
```

The "success" Log printed twice.

Is there something wrong with my code or it should be like this ?

Comment: Perhaps, the first come from cache request

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the answer to this in [the documentation for `ImageLoader.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/ImageLoader.java#118). The documentation states:

> The call flow is this:
>
> 1. Upon being  attached to a request, `onResponse(response, true)` will be invoked to reflect any cached data that was already available. If the data was available, `response.getBitmap()` will be non-null.
> 2. After a network response returns, only one of the following cases will happen:
>
>    - `onResponse(response, false)` will be called if the image was loaded, or
>    - `onErrorResponse` will be called if there was an error loading the image.

Based on this there are three patterns of possible responses. I have tested and confirmed these in a sample application.

#### The image *is* loaded from the cache

In this case there will be one call:

- `onRespsonse(response, true)` will be called, and you can get the image from `response.getBitmap()`.

#### The image is *not* loaded from cache, and *is* loaded from the network

In this case there will be two calls:

- First, `onRespsonse(response, true)` will be called, and `response.getBitmap()` will be `null`.
- Then, `onRespsonse(response, false)` will be called, and you can get the image from `response.getBitmap()`.

#### The image *is not* loaded from cache, and *is not* loaded from the network

In this case there will be two calls:

- First, `onRespsonse(response, true)` will be called, and `response.getBitmap()` will be `null`.
- Then, `onErrorResponse(error)` will be called, and details of the error can be found from `error` (which will be an instance of `VolleyError`).

---

In your case, the following code snippet will help you to skip the first "empty" response:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
    // skip cache failure
    if (isImmediate && response.getBitmap() == null) return;

    // ...
}
```

---

Hopefully this helps to clear up why you may be getting two responses to your request.